# lxml get entire content of a tag including child nodes and text

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml-parsing, lxml

I want to get all text content along with the tags from the below XML

```
<title-group><article-title xml:lang="en">Correction to: Effective adsorptive performance of Fe<sub>3</sub>O<sub>4</sub>@SiO<sub>2</sub>core shell spheres for methylene blue: kinetics, isotherm and mechanism</article-title></title-group>
```

The output for above should be

```
Correction to: Effective adsorptive performance of Fe<sub>3</sub>O<sub>4</sub>@SiO<sub>2</sub>core shell spheres for methylene blue: kinetics, isotherm and mechanism
```

I have tried the following, but it gives me incomplete value

```
        s= '<title-group><article-title xml:lang="en">Correction to: Effective adsorptive performance of Fe<sub>3</sub>O<sub>4</sub>@SiO<sub>2</sub>core shell spheres for methylene blue: kinetics, isotherm and mechanism</article-title></title-group>'
        d = etree.fromstring(s)
        title_xpath = '/title-group/article-title'
        title = ""
        if not d.xpath(title_xpath)[0].getchildren():
            title = d.xpath(title_xpath)[0].text
        else:
            for title_elem in d.xpath(title_xpath):
                title_parts = title_elem.getchildren()
                title = ''.join(etree.tostring(part, encoding="unicode") for part in title_parts)
        print(title)
```

The above code gives me

```
<sub>3</sub>O<sub>4</sub>@SiO<sub>2</sub>core shell spheres for methylene blue: kinetics, isotherm and mechanism
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `BeautifulSoup`,

```
>>> s= '<title-group><article-title xml:lang="en">Correction to: Effective adsorptive performance of Fe<sub>3</sub>O<sub>4</sub>@SiO<sub>2</sub>core shell spheres for methylene blue: kinetics, isotherm and mechanism</article-title></title-group>'

>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'lxml')
>>> soup.getText()
'Correction to: Effective adsorptive performance of Fe3O4@SiO2core shell spheres for methylene blue: kinetics, isotherm and mechanism'
```

Comment: I need the child tags as well.I have updated the expected response in my question, I was using blockquote before which was not rendering the tags

Comment: @Prim What is the difference between your input string and expected output? They both are the same. What you are trying to achieve?

Comment: It doesn't have the enclosing tags `title-group` and `article-title`. For brevity I have not given the whole XML block from which I am extracting this data

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps obtain the  element and extract the text_content() from it.

Starting from your xml tree "d' (this is just off the top of my head and isn't very pretty, but let me know if it gets you what you want):

```
text = ""
for element in list(d.iterchildren("title-group")): # iterate over elements with tag = "title-group"
    try:
        text += element.text_content() # get text, placed in a try-except just incase the element doesn't have the text_content() method
    except:
        continue
print(text)
```